# Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': #<Object> could not be cloned

Tags: vuejs3, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream, laravel-9, pusher-js

I have this Jetstream Laravel application, which has a presence channel set up for chat features.

### What's happening is:

When I join the channel and send a message there, everything works fine, except when I try to exit the channel. In every navigation link, the error [Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': `#<Object>` could not be cloned.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu9zL.png) is triggered.

Not sure what is causing it...

### Curious Fact:

When I join the channel, and leave it, without sending any message, it works as expected. I visit the page that I was supposed to visit, without any error.

Comment: Are you resolve this error ?

Answer (score 4):

You should not change the props who is coming from `$page.props`.{propName}

Instead if you want to make some changes on a prop like your app {messages}

you should create a new object or array from the prop:

```
const messages = ref([...page.props.value.messages]);
```

Now you can change the messages object as many as you want:

```
messages.push(newMessage)
```